# Spring Security - Enable Tomcat session persistence

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-security, tomcat8

We have recently implemented spring security form based login. During restart of server, existing sessions is getting invalidated and the application fails when the server is brought up again.

Is there a way to implement session persistence in tomcat out of box. I have got the `<Manager pathname="" />` commented out in the context.xml but still the sessions are not retained.

Any pointers in getting implemented will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's really all it takes, as long as you're restarting it gracefully (e.g. `shutdown` and `startup` scripts in `./bin`) and giving Tomcat a chance to serialize the sessions to disk

Default **context.xml**

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

Try this:

1. Startup Tomcat, Login to your application to create a session.
2. Stop Tomcat
3. Browse to `{Apache Tomcat}/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT` and you should find the **SESSIONS.ser** file which contains the serialized sessions written to disk.

If you don't see that file then something else is afoot.  Share additional detail if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Does everything in your sessions implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)?

From the [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts):

> In order to successfully restore the state of session attributes, all
>   such attributes MUST implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface.

Usually there is an error message in the Tomcat log if this is the problem.